# Highstock zooming drag rectangle bug

Tags: highcharts, drag, zooming

We are experiencing a similar bug to the one in the jsFiddle below.

When zooming in on the chart, the shaded rectangle does not go away. I don't think the onMouseUp event is working properly in certain cases.

http://jsfiddle.net/mihailiviu/od61d2z3/

Can someone tell us what is causing this and how we can avoid it?

This is how I create the chart:

$(function () {

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart : {
                animation : false,

                zoomType : 'xy',
                events : {
                    redraw : function (event) {}
                }
        },
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        tooltip : {
                enabled : false,
                animation : false,
                useHTML : true,
                formatter : function () {
                    return false;
                },
                crosshairs : [true, true]
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Comment: What is your problem here? The code you posted is fine, but your JSFiddle Highstock core is edited. Did you make the same edit in your own Highstock core code? Why?

Comment: You edit somehitng in code? because with default highstock.js works well http://jsfiddle.net/od61d2z3/2/